# Getting corresponding module from function

Tags: python

I want to modify a module xyz and its functions like that:

```
def modify(fun):
    modulename = fun.__module__ # this is string. ok, but not enough

import xyz
modify(xzy.test)
```

My problem is how to access the namespace of `xzy` inside `modify`. Sometimes

```
globals()[fun.__module__]
```

works. But then I get problems if the definition `modify` is in a different file than the rest of
the code.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You want to get the module object from its name?  Look it up in the `sys.modules` dictionary that contains all currently loaded modules:

```
import sys

def modify(func):
    module = sys.modules[func.__module__]
```

Answer (score 51):

Use the inspect module:

```
import inspect

def modify(fun):
    module = inspect.getmodule(fun)
```

This is the same as polling the module from `sys.modules` using `fun.__module__`. Although `getmodule` tries harder even if `fun` does not have a `__module__` attribute.

Answer (score 13):

You could try

```
modulename = fun.__module__
module = __import__(modulename)
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer, although I have yet to understand the usecase.

Comment: It is for monkey patching. See my coment to Mike Grahams answer.

Answer (score -9):

**You do not want to do this.**

1. **It does not work.** Imagine you defined a function in module `abc` and then imported it in `xyz`. `test.__module__` would be `'abc'` when you called `modify(xyz.test)`. You would then know to change `abc.test` and you would not end up modifying `xyz.test` at all!
2. **Monkey patching should be avoided.** Fooling with the global state of your program is ill-advised. Instead of doing this, why cannot you just make the new, modified thing and use it?

Comment: How can you say that it's a bad idea when you don't know what he is trying to achieve?  Whether it's a good idea or not really depends on the use case.  Maybe he wants to replace a function from an external test script to see how the program behaves in certain situations without messing with the original code.  One size does not fit all!

Comment: @Ferdinand, I offered general advice based on a broad principle, which is the best I can do with the information I have. It's true there *could* be use cases where monkeypatching is the best solution, but that does not change the fact that such things should be avoided in most cases. Your example use case is one that does not at all relieve my apprehension about such an idea, because it's highly prone to error and comes with an unexplained, unreasonable restriction. Although specific concerns applicable to every program are unique, *best practices exist, and it pays to recognize them.*

Comment: In my case I have to use a third party package, where the objects are tight together. Eg you want to modify the behavior of Y which is constructed in the construtor of a class X. If I want a X with a modifed Y I have to derive from X and from Y. Which introduces more dependency than just monkey patching Y. And I do not want do maintain a private fork of the third party lib.

Comment: Please note that the question was **how** to do something, not **if** something should be done.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower, That's a very wrongheaded way to look at things. The goal should never be to answer questions, but to help people. "How" questions can be problematic at a much higher rate than *what* or *why* questions. Consider if someone came and asked, "How do I pull the trigger of a shotgun with my toe?" The best answer is, "Don't".

Comment: Prioritizing helping people is the best way to ensure that people get helped. Taking a literal approach can be fun, but won't maximize actually helping people. We should always focus on helping people right the best programs they can.

Comment: I suffer exactly from point 1. Thanks  @MikeGraham for pointing out the problem here