# How can I know the location of a python function that imported from a library

Tags: python

```
from cs231n.fast_layers import conv_forward_fast, conv_backward_fast

out_fast, cache_fast = conv_forward_fast(x, w, b, conv_param)
```

How can I find the location of the `conv_forward_fast` function with a command?

Comment: Do you mean what module it belongs to? Or where it is in your code?

Comment: What module it belongs to.And where the module is located at.

Comment: I think this may be of some help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027848/getting-corresponding-module-from-function

Answer (score 2):

You can just

```
import cs231n.fast_layers as path
print(path)
```

and it will show you the path of the library.

Comment: Well it give the memory location but what I want is to find the location , where it actually come from.

Comment: ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-da36e4392158> in <module>()
----> 1 import cs231n.fast_layers.conv_forward_fast as path
      2 print(path)

ImportError: No module named conv_forward_fast

Comment: It gives an error "----> 1 import cs231n.fast_layers.conv_forward_fast as path"

Comment: @GayalShamane It looks like `conv_forward_fast` is a function. So it locates in `cs231n.fast_layers`. Try my updated answer.

Comment: yeah But I cannot find that function inside the fast_layers module that's why I asked.I'll see.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x:

```
from os.path import join
path_to_module = __import__(join.__module__).__file__
```