# How to load into Globals in Python from a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, pickle

I have a function which load data into a dictionnary.
But, How can I load the dictionnary into Globals() **inside a function.**

**Inside a function** is important since we can do it easily outside on a script side.

```
def load237(filename):
    filename = osp.abspath(filename)
    old_cwd = os.getcwdu()
    os.chdir(osp.dirname(filename))
    error_message = None
    try:
        tar = tarfile.open(filename, "r")
        tar.extractall()
        pickle_filename = osp.splitext(filename)[0]+'.pickle'
        data = cPickle.load(file(pickle_filename))
        saved_arrays = {}
        if load_array is not None:
            try:
                saved_arrays = data.pop('__saved_arrays__')
                for (name, index), fname in saved_arrays.iteritems():
                    arr = np.load( osp.join(osp.dirname(filename), fname) )
                    if index is None:
                        data[name] = arr
                    elif isinstance(data[name], dict):
                        data[name][index] = arr
                    else:
                        data[name].insert(index, arr)
            except KeyError:
                pass
        for fname in [pickle_filename]+[fn for fn in saved_arrays.itervalues()]:
            os.remove(fname)
    except (EOFError, ValueError), error:
        error_message = unicode(error)
    os.chdir(old_cwd)
    return data, error_message
```

This one does not work (globals is local to the module/function...)

```
def load_inmemory(fpath):
      globals().update(load237(fpath)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really be storing those names on an object stored in a global and not as global variables. But you asked how to do it and so here is how:

Using [Getting corresponding module from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027848/getting-corresponding-module-from-function) with a `for` loop and `setattr` as modules do not support dictionary operations and it is possible to write the function as:

```
import sys

def load_inmemory():
    module = sys.modules[load_inmemory.__module__]
    for k, v in load237(fpath)[0].items():
        setattr(module, k, v)

load_inmemory()
print x
```

I tested the following:

```
import sys

def func():
      module = sys.modules[func.__module__]
      for k,v in {'x':4}.items():
         setattr(module, k, v)

func()
print x
```

Prints `4`. Tested in Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Sounds great, you're a python master.

Why should I store those names into an object and not in Globals ? (this is for running a script after loading the data)