# Python : Get a complete list of external modules imported by my script and their version

Tags: python, python-module

In my script, I imported 5 external modules this way :

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
import pandas
import IPython
from termcolor import cprint
```

I want to get a complete list of external modules and versions imported above, so I wrote the following script :

```
    def imports():
        modulesList = []
        for name, val in globals().items():
            if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
                modulesList.append(val.__name__)
        return modulesList

    import pip
    installed_packages = sorted([ i.key for i in pip.get_installed_distributions() ])
    modules = sorted(imports())
    for module_name in modules:
        module = sys.modules[module_name]
        if module_name.lower() in installed_packages :
            try : moduleVersion = module.__version__
            except : moduleVersion = '.'.join( map(str, module.VERSION) )
            print( "=> Imported %s version %s" % (module_name , moduleVersion) )
```

If I run this script, python shows :

```
=> Imported IPython version 6.0.0
=> Imported numpy version 1.13.1
=> Imported pandas version 0.20.2
```

instead of what I expect, which is the following :

```
=> Imported IPython version 6.0.0
=> Imported numpy version 1.13.1
=> Imported pandas version 0.20.2
=> Imported scipy version 0.19.0
=> Imported termcolor version 1.1.0
```

Can you help ?

Comment: @dlmeetei I don't think so because I used the piece of code coming there and I don't get all the external modules I imported. Can you try and run my code ?

Comment: I thought you are only looking for the one that you have imported. May be you can update that in the question

Comment: @dlmeetei Please read carefully the end of the content. I imported "ipython, numpy, pandas, scipy and termcolor" but this piece of code only outputs "numpy and pandas"

Comment: Just trying to understand " I don't get all the external modules I imported" ? Could you help me what you mean on this

Comment: @dlmeetei When I run the piece of code given above, python outputs only two modules (numpy and pandas) instead of 5 ("ipython, numpy, pandas, scipy and termcolor")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So two things I determined from running your code. IPython isn't getting matched because of the line:

```
if module_name in installed_packages :
```

The installed_packages shows it as 'ipython' while you are checking for 'IPython'.

The second thing is the line:

```
modules = sorted(imports())
```

I'm not sure why but termcolor doesn't show up with

```
from termcolor import cprint
```

but does with

```
import termcolor
```

Not entirely sure what to make of that.

EDIT:

```
def imports():
modulesList = []
for name, val in globals().items():
    if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
        modulesList.append(val.__name__)
    elif isinstance(val, types.FunctionType):
        modulesList.append(sys.modules[val.__module__].__name__)
return modulesList
```

That should get you termcolor.

Comment: Thanks, I added `if module_name.lower() in installed_packages :` to solve the pb. of IPython.

Comment: What about the import `import scipy.io as sio`, why does not it appear ?

Comment: @SebMa similar reason as to why it wasn't finding IPython. The modules variable has scipy.io in it but the installed_packages only has scipy. scipy != scipy.io What you could possibly do is split on '.' and take the first element.

Comment: You're right, I figured this one out in the meantime. But still I cannot understand why `termcolors` is not in the `imports()` result. Any clue ?

Comment: Tracing through the program it looks like cprint is a function and doesn't get added when you check if isinstance of type module. You could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027848/getting-corresponding-module-from-function) and add another if statement checking for functions and then getting the module that function is from.